# Can I replace my old model MBA battery with a 54-watt-hour lithium-polymer battery (12 hrs) for the newest model MBA?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

I have a A1304 MBA and need to replace the battery with a new one.  I was considering to install a 54-watt-hour lithium-polymer battery (12 hours battery life) for the newest model MBA.  Is it compatible to my old model MBA? Will it have a technical problem after I install it?

Answer (score 1):

This won't work. See [Geek.com's teardown](http://www.geek.com/apple/macbook-air-teardown-reveals-bigger-battery-and-pcie-ssd-1558654/) for details, but the battery looks physically larger and differently shaped than the old MBA battery.